# Server Status to XML using fwrite?

Tags: c++

```
// Update the server status xml
            string filelocation ("/var/www/html/index.xml");
            string firstline ("<server>\n");
            string secondline ("\t<current>" + msg.getCount() + "</current>\n");
            string thirdline ("\t<highest>" + "--" + "</highest>\n");
            string fourthline ("\t<status>Online</status>\n")
            string finalline ("</server>");
            fstream  file;
            file.open(filelocation);
            file.write(firstline + secondline + thirdline + fourthline + finalline);
            string updateFlush ("Server Status updated.");
            printf("%s\n", updateFlush);
            file.close();
```

Note that msg.getCount() is a function in the same file to get player count from the central server.

Gives out errors about an operands const char*. Something to do with + or -

Thanks

Comment: `string secondline ("\t<current>" + msg.getCount() + "</current>\n");` Take a look on this line.

Comment: Several of these lines are doing pointer arithmetic not string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the line

```
string secondline ("\t<current>" + msg.getCount() + "</current>\n");
```

`"\t<current>"` is a `const char *`
`msg.getCount()` looks like an `int` or `size_t`
`</current>\n` again is a `const char *`

Adding a `const char *` to an `int` or `size_t` creates a new `const char *` pointing to a different address.

The same happens in the line

```
string thirdline ("\t<highest>" + "--" + "</highest>\n");
```

Here you are adding pointers together. The result is a pointer pointing to a more or less random address.

And in these two lines:

```
string updateFlush ("Server Status updated.");
printf("%s\n", updateFlush);
```

You are creating a C++ string-object and trying to print it using a C print function with a format string that requires a `char *`.

You are mixing C and C++ or stream based I/O with conventional I/O.

In current C++ you should do it this way:

```
string filelocation ("/var/www/html/index.xml");

fstream file;
file.open(filelocation);

file
  << "<server>\n"
  << "\t<current>" << msg.getCount() << "</current>\n"
  << "\t<highest>" << "--" << "</highest>\n"
  << "\t<status>Online</status>\n"
  << "</server>";

string updateFlush ("Server Status updated.");
cout << updateFlush << std::endl;

file.close();
```

Or even more readable:

```
auto file = std::ofstream("/var/www/html/index.xml");
file
  << "<server>" << std::endl
  << "\t<current>" << msg.getCount() << "</current>" << std::endl
  << "\t<highest>" << "--" << "</highest>" << std::endl
  << "\t<status>Online</status>" << std::endl
  << "</server>";

file.close();

std::cout << "Server status updated." << std::endl;
```

If operating with streams use std::endl to output a newline. It outputs the correct newline for the operation system (CRLF or LF or whatever) and it flushes the stream.

To use std::cout you have to include `<iostream>` and for std::ofstream include `<fstream>`.

If you like it short, you could even do this:

```
std::ofstream("/var/www/html/index.xml")
  << "<server>" << std::endl
  << "\t<current>" << msg.getCount() << "</current>" << std::endl
  << "\t<highest>" << "--" << "</highest>" << std::endl
  << "\t<status>Online</status>" << std::endl
  << "</server>";

std::cout << "Server status updated." << std::endl;
```